# C# - Update a subitem within a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, subitem

I am working on an application where users enter information that is then added to a listview.  That works great.  The only problem is, the application connects to a web site that updates the "Points" field in that listview for each account.  I am not sure how I can update a single subitem within a listview.

Here is an example screenshot:

[image]

How can I select a specific subitem in a specific row to update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to assume Windows Forms.

WinForms' ListViewItem class has a [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.name.aspx) property, which you can use to look up a specific item in a list. So as you populate the list, assign a unique value to the Name of each:

```
var item = new ListViewItem("Text");
item.Name = "foo"; // some unique id string
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

That way you can locate the item in the ListView later, using its [Items.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.find.aspx) method.

```
var fooItem = listView1.Items.Find("foo", false);
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Matt's answer, it looks like each row has a unique email address, so you could assign that as the `Name` property for each ListViewItem.  Once you've located the row to update using the `Find` method, you can update that row's Points like this:

```
fooItem.SubItems[2] = "450";
```