# Replacing or updating an entire row (with all subitems) in ListView with new one (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `ListView` and with several rows.  When a new item arrives, I want to replace the existing item/row if they are the same.

Is there a way that I can replace an entire row in the ListView with a new item?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622564/c-sharp-update-a-subitem-within-a-listview

Comment: @BizApps, thanks. but that link is about updating 'SubItems'. i have no problem with that since u can use their index. what i am asking is how can i replace or update the whole items ('SubItem[0]' to 'SubItem[5]')? basically the whole raw is replaced with new one.

Comment: Please, give a more detailed explanation. Simply replacing a row is easy: `listview.Items[index] = new ListViewItem(new String[] { text1, text2, ... });`.

Comment: actually i have an input to the program which comes like every 2 seconds. and the information is posted to the listview. it consists 4 columns. sometimes it detects the same information, so what i want is to replace the old one with the new one, and not only a subitems but the whole items(meaning the row). everytime that the program run, there will be a new input, so i need to update the existing one.

Comment: How about removing old one and adding a new?

Comment: actually i solved with just replacing if there is new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by just replacing the old one if there is new..